# PHP show records from one ID

Tags: php, html, arrays

[image: Overview Screenshot]

Currently I have an overview of domains. I logged in with an account that has the contact ID of 197246. but it shows all of them. Here I want to filter my overview that the user which is logged in, sees his own domains.

So when ID 197246 logs in, show the domains that have contact id 197246. When ID 307890 logs in, show those domains.

This is my code so far. I guess here needs to be a filter.

```html
<?php

unset($command);
$command = array(
 "command" => "DomainsListActive"
);

$api = new Versio_api();
$versio = $api->api_send($command);

if($versio['success']==0) {
 echo("Fout opgetreden. Fout code: ".$versio['command_response_code'].". Fout text: ".$versio['command_response_message']."");
}
else {
 if($versio['total_count']>0)
 {
require_once("includes/submenu.php");
?>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" style="width:80%;">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Klantenpaneel</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
   <form method="post" action="">
    <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
       <tr>
      <th>Domein</th>
      <th>TLD</th>
      <th>Verloop datum</th>
      <th>Automatisch verlengen</th>
      <th>contact ID</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <tbody>
<?php 
 $teller = 1;
 while($versio['total_count']>=$teller) {
?>
       <tr>
      <td><a href="records.php?domain=<?php echo        $versio['domain_'.$teller]; ?>&tld=<?php echo $versio['tld_'.$teller]; ?>">
      <?php echo $versio['domain_'.$teller]; ?></a></td>
      <td>.<?php echo $versio['tld_'.$teller]; ?></td> 
      <td><?php echo $versio['expiration_date_'.$teller]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $versio['auto_renew_'.$teller]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $versio['contactid_'.$teller]; ?></td>
       </tr>
<?php       $teller++;
     }
?> 
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
<?php
 } else {
  echo("Er zijn geen DNS records gevonden voor dit domein.");
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: could you show me what the versio_api does with that command? there should be a filter that allows you to send an ID in there.

Comment: Either the API you're using has a way to filter/query data, or you filter manually by making comparisons in your loop when displaying records.  Which option are you using and what have you tried?

Comment: It totally depends on `Versio_api()` That what does it accept and what does it return..

Comment: @Tosfera https://www.versio.nl/api-doc/ DomainsListActive

Comment: @David haven't tried any, i've got a blackout so i don't know any solusions haha

Comment: the API doesn't accept any input, I've posted an answer on how to do it. If you need some sample code, refresh your page in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation from Versio gives you an entire list of options in the call. One option you could do is check if the 'contactid_x' equals to the logged in user.

more information on their wiki [right here](https://www.versio.nl/api-doc/pages/DomainsListActive.html)

---

As an example, this would do the trick:

```
unset($command);
$command = array(
    "command" => "DomainsListActive"
);

$api = new Versio_api();
$versio = $api->api_send($command);

if($versio['success']==0) {
    echo("Fout opgetreden. Fout code: ".$versio['command_response_code'].". Fout text: ".$versio['command_response_message']."");
}
else {
    if($versio['total_count']>0)
    {
require_once("includes/submenu.php");
?>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" style="width:80%;">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Klantenpaneel</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form method="post" action="">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Domein</th>
                        <th>TLD</th>
                        <th>Verloop datum</th>
                        <th>Automatisch verlengen</th>
                        <th>contact ID</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
<?php 
    $teller = 1;
    while($versio['total_count']>=$teller) {
        if ($versio['contactid_'. $teller] != 197246 ) continue;
?>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a href="records.php?domain=<?php echo        $versio['domain_'.$teller]; ?>&tld=<?php echo $versio['tld_'.$teller]; ?>">
                        <?php echo $versio['domain_'.$teller]; ?></a></td>
                        <td>.<?php echo $versio['tld_'.$teller]; ?></td> 
                        <td><?php echo $versio['expiration_date_'.$teller]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $versio['auto_renew_'.$teller]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $versio['contactid_'.$teller]; ?></td>
                      </tr>
<?php                 $teller++;
                    }
?> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    } else {
        echo("Er zijn geen DNS records gevonden voor dit domein.");
    }
}
?>
```

make sure to replace the ID with the ID from the user on line 41

Comment: That is the one i'm using, I think i have to check if the 'contactid_x' equals to the logged in user but don't know how. maybe it is so easy that i forgot how...

Comment: If you saved the ID from the user in an session, you can simply replace '197246' with $_SESSION['<your id key']. If you're using a framework, there should be an easy way to do it.

Comment: When I use your code i won't get any results.. I dont know why. I tried with 197246 but he does not show my example. Any idea's?

Comment: try to see what's in the $versio['contactid_'. $teller], it might be something else than the API documentation states. Also, your ID which you're using might be the one from the user's account, not the contactid from Versio.

Comment: When I try  if ($versio['contactid_'. $teller] == 197246 ) continue;
he does filter that one and show the others. So I don't know why he doesnt show 1 record when != ....  $versio['contactid_'. $teller] gives the ID of DomainListContacts from the API. So I wanted to make an account for the contact and show their domains based on the ID's.

Comment: well.. you probably have to save the 'contactid_N' to the account of the user and use that in your if-statement. the 'continue' tells the loop to skip the functionality if it returns true.